# I am unable to start up my React Native app on Windows using Android emulator from Android Studio

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, android-emulator

I am new to React Native and Mobile App Development. I am trying to start up my bare React Native project in my Emulator and it gives me issue to set up.

I get this error when I click on the button a to set to Android Emulator from my command terminal

Couldn't adb reverse: adb.exe: error: device offline
Couldn't start project on Android: Error running adb: device offline

please how do I fix it

here is my system variable
C:\Users\JUWONCALEB.DESKTOP-CMA289U\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

Answer (score 0):

running adb devices after running adb kill-server. Security question pops up after that. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

1/ run `npm start`

2/ go to `http://localhost:19002`

3/ press on Lan and copy the URL under it eg. `exp://192.168.1.3:19000`

4/ download expo app in your device from your android studio.

5/ open expo and click `Enter URL manually` and paste the URL u copied in the previous step

6/ if needed: reload by clicking "r" button in your command line

Answer (score 0):

Try to:

1 Launch the android emulator (any sdk is fine as any model)

2 open the settings IN the emulator

3 activate developer mode

Comment: once i press the last three dots beside my emulator and it brings p the settings bar , i can finde the dev mode

Comment: don't worry, see this article for reference

https://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/how-to-get-developer-options-on-android/